# Python:Errno 10053 when both the server and the client are in the same system

Tags: python

I'm just beginning to code using Python and Python Networking is a whole new topic for me!I couldn't find out what the problem was and I say, I have tried all the solutions provided by the user!

Please help me with this code!

Server Code:

```
from socket import *
import time

HostName = ''
PortNum = 2015
Buff = 5000
ServAdd = (HostName, PortNum)
ServSoc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
ServSoc.bind(ServAdd)
ServSoc.listen(5)

while 1:
    CliAdd = ServSoc.accept()
    TempSoc = ServSoc.accept()
    while 1:
        CliData = TempSoc.recv(Buff)
        print CliData
        time.sleep(20)
        TempSoc.send('Hai')
    TempSoc.close()
ServSoc.close()
```

Client Code:

```
from socket import *
import time

HostName = 'localhost'
PortNum = 2015
Buff = 5000
ServAdd = (HostName, PortNum)

CliSoc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
CliSoc.connect(ServAdd)

while 1:
    Data = raw_input('Enter Data to sent to the Server: ')
    CliSoc.send(Data)
    ServData = CliSoc.recv(Buff)
    print ServData
    time.sleep(10)
CliSoc.close()
```

The Error message is

```
Enter Data to sent to the Server: hello

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/Progs/TCPClient.py", line 15, in <module>
    ServData = CliSoc.recv(Buff)
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following server code. Your client side seems ok. You have to run server.py first to listen related port. Then run your client.py. What you do at the server side is creating a socket to listen (which is "ServSoc" in your case) and accept connections. Connections are not socket objects so using `close()` function is not meaningful. Following server code accepts connections in a loop and check client connection. Thus, it wont crush when client disconnects.

**Server code:**

```
from socket import *
import time

HostName = ''
PortNum = 2015
Buff = 5000
ServAdd = (HostName, PortNum)
ServSoc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
ServSoc.bind(ServAdd)
ServSoc.listen(5)

while 1:
    conn, addr = ServSoc.accept()
    if conn:
        print "connection established with client:",addr
        CliData = conn.recv(Buff)
        print CliData
        time.sleep(1)
        conn.send('Hai')
ServSoc.close()
```